# What are the options available for the archival of the data of Document Library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, retention, modern, document-archiving

We have a couple of document libraries in which there is a large amount of data.

i.e., one of the document libraries has 1,99,936 items in it.

We are looking for the best archival option so that the current site doesn't get slow due to a large amount of data and also we want to avoid the issues with Search as the threshold limit is crossed.

Below are some of the options we found for the Archival of SharePoint Online Document Library,

1. Manually move the older files to other locations / delete them.
2. Set retention policy.
3. Create a flow on a particular document library to move the files to other locations over a specific time period.

Is there any other option available for the archival?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sites don't get "slow" due to data set size. If you do find any performance issues, you can open a case with Microsoft as performance is their responsibility.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but we also want to avoid issues with search.

Comment: Search can handle hundreds of millions of files so I don't know what issues you're expecting to encounter.

Comment: So currently, we are facing the issue where some of the action buttons like, Move To and Copy To are not appearing or not working if users are searching in these document libraries which has more than 2lac items

Answer (score 1):

**You can refer to the following two methods. These methods are more of a “workaround” and not a true archival technique.**

**1.SECURITY TRIMMING**

The idea behind this approach is that you would be setting up **[unique permissions](https://sharepointmaven.com/6-locations-can-set-security-files-sharepoint-office-365/)** for certain folders you need to “archive”, thus making them invisible to the end-users. So, in reality, folders will still be there, just hidden.

`Note:`

- Folders/Files cannot be hidden from the Site Owners/Site Collection
  Administrators.**Only Site Members and Site Visitors**.

**2.CUSTOM METADATA/FILTERING**

The idea behind this method is that you will need to **create a custom metadata column** on a library called “Status” (or whatever you want to call it) with a few drop-down choices (i.e., Active/Inactive). Once tagged, this will allow you to filter out (hide) the Inactive files.

`Note:`

- **Can only tag files, not folders**
- Requires consistency in tagging if you would like to utilize across
  multiple sites/libraries

Comment: Hi, Litt Spector. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!